# Is there an inconsistency in the fate of evil souls in Dragon Ball?

Tags: anime, dragon-ball

I have a question that I've been wanting to ask. My native language is Spanish (Latin America) so much of the Dragon Ball series lacks of consistency because of the translation.

My question is about the fate of evil souls: in episode 237 Pikkoro warns Vegeta about never being able to be meet Goku because his soul would forget all memories and would be used for another being.

Nevertheless, later we can see eviler souls (i.e. Freeza, Cell) capable of remembering things.

I wonder if this is explained, just a 'void' in Dragon Ball's story, or maybe even due to a bad translation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is inconsistency.

This is possibly a translation error. In the English (Funimation) version of the show it is quite clear that Vegeta will be going to Hell along with Freeza and Cell. However, in other spots in the same translation there are similar references made about people losing their body when they die. Nothing about recycling the soul, but this explains the little ghosts you see floating around.

It is explained when Goku first arrives in Other World way back in the beginning of Dragon Ball Z, that the Kai allow certain people to retain their body as a reward so they can train forever.

It is unclear why exactly Cell and Freeza and others are allowed this privilege.

[There are some more details on the Dragon Ball wiki.](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Other_World)

> Piccolo tells Vegeta that Goku kept his body when he died because he sacrificed himself to save the world from Cell, and devoted his life to fighting for good, and that Vegeta won't keep his body if he dies because he spent most of his life fighting for evil. However, true villains like Frieza, Cell, King Cold, Recoome, Burter, Jeice, Guldo, Dr. Gero, Appule, and Babidi did keep their bodies after death (the Ginyu Force can be explained because King Kai invited them over to show that Yamcha, Tien, and Chiaotzu could beat them, but the reason behind the others is unknown). Also, Piccolo, despite initially having an evil heart when he first died, was not only allowed to keep his body, but he also was allowed to go to King Kai's planet.

Answer (score 4):

Filler is the reason for the inconsistency.  Scenes with Cell and Frieza in Hell did not exist in the manga, and, using that as the "real" canon, Cell and Frieza should have been rehashed into a new existence as well.

Comment: This is no longer true post Resurrection-F

Answer (score 2):

But when Vegeta confronted Goku about not fighting to his fullest strength against him, Vegeta told him he viewed SSJ3 from Other World. How was he able to see it? That big crystal ball that Cell, Freeza, and the other bad dudes watched the Buu vs Goku fight on was created by Babbidi I suppose. Babbidi died right as the boys started training for Fusion. But Vegeta would not have been able to see this without a body would he? Maybe even as a spirit "aka a little white ghost" he could somehow since the power surge from ol' Goku. But I am more than willing to look over the very minor flaws or inconsistencies in DBZ because it is hands down the best action cartoon ever made.

I also think it's pretty damn cool that Trunks called Goku "Uncle" in the Japanese version right when Fusion training began. Goten did the same of Vegeta right before the prince blew himself up. Kinda crazy if you think about it. Its a damn good thing Goku and Krillin spared him or else DBZ would not have been NEAR as good!!

Comment: An you are correct by the way, MHero. The translations change a lot of the story. The English version makes them much more goofy and ignorant (especially Krillin) and makes Goku out to be everyone's savior and hero more than he was intended to be. Another big difference is that around the episodes when Gohan first fought Buu, Piccolo was more worried about the Kai rather than Gohan. I think the English version was more concerned with making it less violent with deeper character emotion/bonds and more kid friendly. Still good stuff, but takes away from the true meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is ,but,  Akira Toriyama didn't write Dragon Ball GT and also no manga exists about Dragon Ball gt. Usually the anime does not follow the mangas history, that is why some inconsistencies are created